# Run shell script after reboot in beaglebone black

Tags: cron, autostart, beagleboneblack

I'm using a beaglebone black which works with Debian 8.6. I want to start a program after reboot. I tried `crontab` but it didn't work.

```
@reboot sleep 60 && /home/debian/acspilot/start.sh
```

Program consists of a config.sh file and a acsp.py python script. Each code works fine from terminal. Here are the codes:

`start.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo su
cd home/debian/acs/
./config_pins.sh
python acsp.py
```

`config_pins.sh` :

```
#! /bin/bash
cd /sys/devices/platform/bone_capemgr
File=slots
if grep -q "Override Board Name,00A0,Override Manuf,univ-emmc" "$File"; 
then    
        cd
        echo -e "\nHooray!! configuration available"
        echo -e "\n UART 4 configuration p9.11 and p9.13"
        sudo config-pin P9.11 uart
        sudo config-pin -q P9.11
        sudo config-pin P9.13 uart
        sudo config-pin -q P9.13
        echo -e "\n UART 1 configuration p9.26 and p9.24"
        sudo config-pin P9.24 uart
        sudo config-pin -q P9.24
        sudo config-pin P9.26 uart
        sudo config-pin -q P9.26
        echo -e "\n UART 5 configuration p8.38 and p8.37"
        sudo config-pin P8.38 uart
        sudo config-pin -q P8.38
        sudo config-pin P8.37 uart
        sudo config-pin -q P8.37
        echo -e "\n UART configuration end" 
else    
        echo "Oops!!configuration is not available"
        echo "Please check uEnv.txt file and only disable HDMI"
fi
```

acsp.py:

```
import Adafruit_BBIO.PWM as PWM
import Adafruit_BBIO.UART as UART
import time
# UART communication begins
UART.setup("UART1")
# pwm begins
PWM.start("P9_14", 5,50)
ser = serial.Serial(port = "/dev/ttyO1", baudrate=9600)
ser.close()
ser.open()
while ser.isOpen():
      for i in range(1,99)
            print i
            ser.write(str(i)+"%")
            PWM.set_duty_cycle("P9_14", i)
            time.sleep(5)
ser.close()
UART.cleanup()
PWM.stop("P9_14")
PWM.cleanup()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script has a sudo'ed line, and if it is cronned to a non-root user, the shell cannot be executed by itself. Instead you should first be root with

```
sudo su -
```

And then

```
crontab -e
```

as root user and add the task line

Comment: it didnt worked for me

Comment: To recommendations:

Comment: Two recommendations: First, you can delete the "sudo su" line out. Second, change cd home/... to cd /home/...

Comment: Furthermore, is config_pins.sh executable with chmod +x?

Comment: And you may use absolute paths for config_pins.sh and acsp.py

Comment: There is a whitespace after shebang in config_pins.sh " #! / ", etc etc. Maybe you can run the scripts (start and config_pins) first in debug mode with bash -x, and see the output.

Comment: I did what you wrote also changed bin/bash to bin/sh and now Works. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. In fact /bin/sh is a symlink to /usr/bin/bash (and /bin is a symlink to /usr/bin)